# Regular Expression Pattern With A Variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using regular expression to check number of digits after decimal.

This is working fine when it is used for two or three digits, for example `\d{2}` or `\d{3}`, but what if I need to pass a variable instead of `2` and `3`?

How do I pass a variable to the pattern? Is it possible?

Comment: You'd have to build the RegExp as a string.

Comment: could you please show me how to do that ,,,, how do i build that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **RegExp**, like;

```
//just an example though
var i = 2;
var pattern = new RegExp("\\d{"+i+"}$");
```

Comment: Double backslash instead of one.

Comment: This worked for me  var no=2;
 var rxDatePattern = new RegExp("^(?:\\d*\\.\\d{" + no + "})$");

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that generates the RegEx string with the parameter you provide for the number or decimal digits you need.

Comment: could you help me out with an example ,,,, as m relatively new to regular expressions

Comment: function getRegEx(int len) { return "\d{" + len + "}"; } and then you generate the RegEx with: reg_ex = getRexEx(6) to generate a RegEx to check for 6 decimal digits. You can't put variable in RegEx you need to create a string for them.

Comment: Thanks Odinn ,,, i understood your example..It helped me a lot..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about just defining the range of the digits: `\d{2,3}`?

Comment: Something like this should work : var i=2, j=3, regex = new RegExp("^\\d{"+ i +","+ j +"}$", "g");

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful : [10+ Useful JavaScript Regular Expression Functions to improve your web applications efficiency](http://ntt.cc/2008/05/10/over-10-useful-javascript-regular-expression-functions-to-improve-your-web-applications-efficiency.html)