# Variable in match (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<body class="reviews"></body>

var body = document.body;
var target = 'reviews';

if (body.className.match('/\b' + target + '\b/'))
    console.log(true);
else
    console.log(false);
```

This code returns `false`. But if I use `body.className.match(/\breviews\b/)` it returns `true`.

What's wrong with it?

I tried to escape a variable in a regex, no luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression Pattern With A Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513431/regular-expression-pattern-with-a-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching for the literal string `'/\breviews\b/'`, it's not being read as a RegEx.

You need to use the `new RegExp` method.

```
body.className.match(new RegExp('\\b' + target + '\\b'))
```

Note: Don't use delimiters with `new RegExp`.  Also, note that `\\b` has 2 `\`.

Comment: Double-escape the `\\b` inside the quoted string?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Thanks, forgot about that :-)