# Create Regex from a string variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, variables

```
var tags=["div","span","body"];
for (i=0; i<=tags.length; i++){
  source = source.replace(/\&lt\;<tags[i]/i, '<span class="tags[i]">&lt;tags[i]</span>');
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to put all the opening div,span and body tags around a span with a class set accordingly. But, I am having issues getting the variables inside there.

I can put lines and lines for each different tag but considering this function is called on every key press I want to keep the code as small and efficient as possible.

Or are there other alternatives? I mean it would be even better if something along these lines was possible:

```
source = source.replace(/\&lt\;<div|<span/i, '<span class="div|span">&lt;div|span</span>');
```

But, it clearly does not get me anywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression Pattern With A Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513431/regular-expression-pattern-with-a-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct your regex from a string using the RegExp object:

```
source = source.replace(new RegExp("\\&lt\\;<" + tags[i], "i"), '<span class="' + tags[i] + '">&lt;' + tags[i] + '</span>');
```

But your idea for an alternative is also possible by capturing the tag and referencing it in the replacement:

```
source = source.replace(/\&lt\;<(div|span|body)/i, '<span class="$1">&lt;$1</span>');
```

Comment: Ah that works like a charm, I definately prefer the alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexes with `| (equivalent of OR)`: `()` are used to get the matched elements (div, span or body), and you can get them with `$1`

```
source.replace(/<(div|span|body)/i,'<span class="$1">&lt;$1&gt;</span>')
```