# how to include a variable value into regex pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to include a value of variable into regex pattern.

**The following code is the familiar.**

```
var regex = /(.)\1{2}/;
```

**I want to do like The following.**

```
var number = 2;
var regex = /(.)\1{number}/
```

**How to do that ?**

Comment: Wildly guessing: `new Regex('/(.)\{'+number+'}/')`

Comment: That should be an answer.

Comment: and [Regular Expression Pattern With A Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9513431/218196) (this is actually describing the *exact* same problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var number = 2;
var regex = new RegExp('(.)\\1{'+number+'}');
```

Comment: Can you tell me why double \  `\\1`?

Comment: @LionKing You have to escape the \ to have a \ in your string.